# no data to retrieve from fire_base and there's a malfunction with the adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout #1

this is the message which i had when i build the app for the first time , so any help please ?

public class Images_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<Upload> mUploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_images_);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(Images_Activity.this, mUploads);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to use instead of `Images_Activity.this` to call `getApplicationContext()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` in event listener.

Outside the listener or even  before  valueEventListener can work

Comment: Still the same issue after make it outside the listener :/

Comment: See what databaseError gives the message